# lambda task timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing a Lambda function in Python 3.6 which Connects an Alexa skill to a very shallow MySQL database. I'm having some difficulty with the lambda function timing out; I keep getting a time out error. Here is (most recent) error:

{
  "errorMessage": "2018-04-11T00:29:23.341Z 49ebf0c0-3d1f-11e8-899e-61ea93a8a4cb Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"
}

I don't think its my code. Here's why. I built my lambda based off of the Amazon Alexa Color Lambda 'blue print', but that template also doesn't run for me. I have also tried creating different lambdas with templates using the AWS CLI and am getting the same 'Timed Out' error.

Here is the command I am using to create my lambdas:

```
aws lambda create-function \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --function-name WallyFlow \ 
    --zip-file fileb://~/wallyflow_lambda.zip \ 
    --runtime python3.6 \ 
    --profile wallyflow_admin \  
    --timeout 30 \ 
    --memory-size 1024 \ 
    --handler wallyflow_lambda.handler \ 
    --role arn:aws:iam::517237838660:role/lambda-s3-execution-role
```

*Note: I am using this method because I need the deployment package to include the mysql library.*

I have tried different lambda functions (even programs not using mysql), increasing the timeout up to 300, and doubling the memory to 2048.

My thoughts are that the problem lies in the role or profile, but, even though I've read the official documentation and supplementary materials, I'm having trouble pinning down the problem.

Can someone please help?

I've included my lambda function below on the off chance that is the problem.

```
    import MySQLdb

    db = MySQLdb.connect(user="*****",
                     passwd="*****",
                     port=*****,
                     host="*****",
                     db="*****")
    cursor = db.cursor()


    def build_speechlet_response(title, output, reprompt_text, 
    should_end_session):
         return {
        'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'PlainText',
            'text': output
        },
        'card': {
            'type': 'Simple',
            'title': "SessionSpeechlet - " + title,
            'content': "SessionSpeechlet -" + output
        },
        'reprompt':{
            'outputSpeech': {
                'type': 'PlainText',
                'text': reprompt_text
            }
        },
        'shouldEndSession': should_end_session
    }

def build_response(session_attributes, speechlet_response):
    return {
        'version': '1.0',
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'response': speechlet_response
    }

########################################################
def get_welcome_response():
    session_attributes={}
    card_title = "Welcome"
    speech_output = "Welcome to Wally Flow, mindfulness with Walabot and Alexa."\
                    "How can I help you?"
    reprompt_text = "I'm sorry. I didn't catch that." \
                    "How can I help you?"

    should_end_session = False
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,speech_output,
                                                   reprompt_text,should_end_session))
def get_mst_response():
    session_attributes={}
    card_title = "Maximum Still Time"
    sql = "SELECT MaxStillTime FROM wallyflowdb.mstTable ORDER BY initTime DESC LIMIT 1"
    cursor.execute(sql)   
    mst = cursor.fetchone()
    speech_output = "Your maximum still time is set to {}.".format(mst[0])
    reprompt_text = None
    should_end_session = False
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,speech_output,
                                                   reprompt_text,should_end_session))
def get_mc_response():
    session_attributes={}
    card_title="Move Count"
    sql = "SELECT MoveCount FROM wallyflowdb.mcTable ORDER BY initTime DESC LIMIT 1"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    mc = cursor.fetchone()
    speech_output = "Your current movement count is {}.".format(mc[0])
    reprompt_text = None
    should_end_session = False
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,speech_output,
                                                   reprompt_text,should_end_session))
def get_stillTime_response():
    session_attributes={}
    card_title="Stillness Time"
    sql = "SELECT StillTime FROM wallyflowdb.stillTable ORDER BY initTime DESC LIMIT 1"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    stillTime = cursor.fetchone()
    speech_output = "Your current movement count is {}.".format(stillTime[0])
    reprompt_text=None
    should_end_session=False
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,speech_output,
                                                   reprompt_text,should_end_session))
def get_lmt_response():
    session_attributes={}
    card_title="Last Move Time"
    sql = "SELECT LastMoveTime FROM wallyflowdb.lmtTable ORDER BY initTime DESC LIMIT 1"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    lmt = cursor.fetchone()
    speech_output = "Your last move time was {}".format(lmt[0])
    reprompt_text=None
    should_end_session=False
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,speech_output,
                                                   reprompt_text,should_end_session))
def get_startTime_response():
    session_attributes = {}
    card_title="Start Time"
    sql = "SELECT StartTime FROM wallyflowdb.stTable ORDER BY initTime DESC LIMIT 1"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    startTime = cursor.fetchone()
    speech_output = "You started this mindfulness session at {}".format(startTime[0])
    reprompt_text=None
    should_end_session=False
    return build_response(session_attributes,
                          build_speechlet_response(card_title,speech_output,
                                                   reprompt_text,should_end_session))    
def handle_session_end_request():
    card_title = "Session Ended"
    speech_output = "Thank you for using Wally Flow, mindfulness with Walabot and Alexa."\
                    "Have a mindful day!"
    should_end_session = True
    return build_response({}, build_speechlet_response(
        card_title, speech_output, None, should_end_session))

###########################################################################
#Events

def on_session_started(session_started_request, session):
    #Called when session starts
    print("on_session_started requestId=" + session_started_request['requestId']
          +", sessionId=" +session['sessionId'])

def on_launch(launch_request, session):
    #Called when the user launches the skill without specifiying what they want
    print("on_launch requestId=" + launch_request['requestId'] +
          " , sessionId =" + session['sessionId'])
    #Dispatch to your skill's launch
    return get_welcome_response()

def on_intent(intent_request, session):
    #Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill
    print("on_intent requestId =" + intent_request['requestId'] +
          ", sessiodId=" + session['sessionId'])
    intent = intent_request['intent']
    intent_name = intent_request['intent']['name']

    if intent_name == "MaxStillTimeIntent":
        return get_mst_response()
    elif intent_name == "MoveCountIntent":
        return get_mc_response()
    elif intent_name == "StillTimeIntent":
        return get_stillTime_response()
    elif intent_name == "LastMoveTimeIntent":
        return get_lmt_response()
    elif intent_name == "StartTimeIntent":
        return get_startTime_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return get_welcome_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.CANCELIntent" or intent_name == "AMAZON.StopIntent":
        return handle_session_end_request()
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid intent")


def on_session_ended(session_ended_request, session):
    #Called when the user ends the session
    #Not called when the skil returns should_ends_session=True
    print("on_session_ended requestId=" + session_ended_request['requestId'] +
          ", sessionId=" + session['sessionId'])
    #add cleanup logic here

###############################################################
#Main Handler
def wallyflow_lambda(event, context):
    """
    Route the incoming request based on type (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest, etc.)
    The JSON body of the request is provided in the event parameter
    """
    print("event.session.application.applicationId=" +
          event['session']['application']['applicationId'])

    if (event['session']['application']['applicationId'] !=
        "amzn1.ask.skill.1a61b436-2b39-448c-a2bb-1ad391fe666b"):
        raise ValueError("Invalid Application ID")

    if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started({'requestId': event['request']['requestId']},event['session'])

    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event['request'],event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return on_intent(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_session_ended(event['request'], event['session'])
```

Comment: Is your MySql in a vpc?